# I can't animate UICollectionViewCell subclass or any of it's subviews

Tags: ios, swift

I have an animation function which I use in many other parts of the app and it works perfectly:

```
class func pulse(view: UIView, sizeMultiplier: Float, duration: NSTimeInterval, repeatCount: Float = 1.0) {
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulseAnimation.duration = duration
    pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: sizeMultiplier)
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    view.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

For some reason though, I can't animate a cell in my `UICollectionView`

In my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function (which is being called, I checked with breakpoints), I have this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ModuleCell        
Animations.pulse(cell, sizeMultiplier: 2.0, duration: 0.2, repeatCount: 2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

You currently create / dequeue a new cell rather than retrieving the current cell.